# chrome extension: get storage value and pass to another function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I get a value from Chrome storage using chrome.storage.local.get(). I need to be able to use this value in a function.

What I really want to do is to access the_userid outside of the get function, but that does not work:

```
function my_f(userid){
  alert("I'm called");
}

var the_userid;
chrome.storage.local.get('userid', function (result) {
    the_userid = userid.result;
 }

my_f(the_user_id);
```

So I figured it would work to pass the function my_f:

```
function my_f(userid){
  alert("I'm called");
}

chrome.storage.local.get('userid', function (result, my_f) {
    var the_userid = userid.result;
    my_f(the_user_id);
 }
```

But my_f is not called.

what to do?

Comment: In manifest? I have done that. I can get the value of userid. I just can't use it anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it almost right in your second attempt. You are correct to move the call to `my_f` inside the callback function.

*However*, you have declared an argument called `my_f` in the callback that "shadows" the original `my_f` from the outer scope. Since `chrome.storage.local.get` only passes one argument to its callback (which you have named `result`), other arguments are assigned the value `undefined`. Thus, the variable `my_f` inside your callback in `undefined`.

Instead, just remove the `my_f` argument:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('userid', function (result) {
    var the_userid = userid.result;
    my_f(the_user_id);
}
```

and then the variable `my_f` in the callback will refer to the `my_f` function defined in the outer scope.